# Variable is not defined: but I think it is

Tags: python, variables

I'm new to coding, especially in python. I started learning python using codeacademy about 1 day ago and I have progressed quickly. After reaching the end of the battleship unit, it challenged me to challenge myself by seeing what I can do. So, I set out to make the game two-player. However, after finishing the program, it tells me that the column variable on the second player's ship is not defined. Why?

Here is the code:

```
board1 = []
board2 = []
for i in range(5):
    board1.append(["O"] * 5)
    board2.append(["O"] * 5)
# Creates 2 boards, one for each player to view

def printboard(board):
    for row in board:
        print "  ".join(row)
# Prints one of the boards, depending on which player is meant to see it

def boardset1():
    print "Player 1, set your coordinates!"
    ship_col1 = int(raw_input("X:"))
    ship_row1 = int(raw_input("Y:"))
    if ship_col1 not in range(1,6) or ship_row1 not in range(1,6):
        print "Invalid coordinates!"
        boardset1()
    else:
        ship_col1 = abs(ship_col1 - 5)
        ship_row1 = abs(ship_row1 - 5)
        for i in range(10):
            print ""
        print "Coordinates set!"

def boardset2():
    print "Player 2, set your coordinates!"
    ship_col2 = int(raw_input("X:"))
    ship_row2 = int(raw_input("Y:"))
    if ship_col2 not in range(1,6) or ship_row2 not in range(1,6): #< Issue is here, I think
        print "Invalid coordinates!"
        boardset2()
    else:
        ship_col2 = abs(ship_col2 - 5) #< Might be here
        ship_row2 = abs(ship_row2 - 5)
        for i in range(10):
            print ""
        print "Coordinates set!"
# 2 above functions set coordinates based on player input

def play1():
    printboard(board1)
    print "Player 1: Where is the opponent's ship?"
    guess_col1 = int(raw_input("X:"))
    guess_row1 = int(raw_input("X:"))
    if guess_col1 not in range(1,6) or guess_row1 not in range(1,6):
        print "Invalid coordinates!"
        play1()
    else:
        guess_col1 = abs(guess_col1 - 5)
        guess_row1 = abs(guess_row1 - 5)
        if board1[guess_col1][guess_row1] == "X":
            print "You already guessed here!"
            play1()
        elif guess_col1 == ship_col2 and guess_row1 == ship_row2:
            win = True
            print "You have won!"
        else:
            board1[guess_col1][guess_row1] = "X"
        print "You have missed!"

def play2():
    if win == False:
        printboard(board2)
        print "Player 2: Where is the opponent's ship?"
        guess_col2 = int(raw_input("X:"))
        guess_row2 = int(raw_input("X:"))
        if guess_col2 not in range(1,6) or guess_row2 not in range(1,6):
            print "Invalid coordinates!"
            play2()
        else:
            guess_col2 = abs(guess_col2 - 5)
            guess_row2 = abs(guess_row2 - 5)
            if board2[guess_col2][guess_row2] == "X":
                print "You already guessed here!"
                play2()
            elif guess_col2 == ship_col1 and guess_row2 == ship_row1:
                win = True
                print "You have won!"
            else:
                board2[guess_col2][guess_row2] = "X"
            print "You have missed!"
# Play functions are for gameplay
win = False
boardset1()
boardset2()

for i in range(25):
    if win == False:
        play1()
        play2()
    else:
        break
```

Immediately after player 1 makes a guess, this error occurs:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "python", line 97, in <module>
      File "python", line 59, in play1
    NameError: global name 'ship_col2' is not defined
```

Any advice or solution is welcome. The more detailed, the better, as I am still learning.

Thanks!

Comment: `ship_col2` is define *inside the function `boardset2`*. It is therefore not global, and definitely not visible inside the `play1` function.

Comment: `boardset1()` needs `global ship_col1, ship_col2` to be added at the beginning.  It is defining local variables that are available only inside that function.  Making them global means that other functions can use them.

Comment: Advice: avoid global variables, and pass the variables as function arguments to functions, and return them at the end of a function (e.g., inside a tuple) to the code that called the function.

Comment: You can make this a lot shorter and easier to reason about by writing your functions to take the inputs they need as parameters instead of using globals or values implicitly defined elsewhere. You won't need separate functions for the different players or board set ups either since they do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the variable `ship_col2` is defined within a function. That means that it only exists until that function is done running, and then it is deleted. In order to make it available outside that function and in other functions, you must declare it as a global variable, which you can do by defining it with a default value under `board1` and `board2` at the top of the file. You must define all variables that you want to use in multiple functions like that.

Here is some further reading that might help you understand better: http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html